# How to discriminate while decoding using Codable Protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I am using Swift's Codable Protocol. I have shared the code.

I want the variable boss in the class Employee to acquire the type based on the personType String in the Person class. I want to use personType as discriminator. Response coming from the server will be different every time based on the personType value.

In Employee class, I have declared the boss variable with Person type. I want it to decode for type Employee if the personType string in the Person class is "Employee" and decode for type Boss if the personType string is "Boss". If it is null I simply want it to decode for type Person.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
public class Person: Codable {

    public let address: String
    public let age: Int
    public let name: String
    public let uid: String
    public let personType: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address
        case age
        case name
        case uid
        case personType
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        address = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        uid = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .uid)
        personType = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .personType)
    }
}


public class Employee: Person {

    public let department: String
    public let dependents: [Person]?
    public let salary: Int
    public let workingDays: [Days]
    public var boss: Person?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case department
        case dependents
        case salary
        case workingDays
        case boss
    }


    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        department = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .department)
        dependents = try container.decode([Person].self, forKey: .dependents)
        salary = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .salary)
        workingDays = try container.decode([Days].self, forKey: .workingDays)
        boss = try container.decode(Person.self, forKey: .boss)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

}



public class Boss: Employee {
    let promotedAt: Double
    let assistant: Employee?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case promotedAt
        case assistant
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        promotedAt = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .promotedAt)
        assistant = try container.decodeIfPresent(Employee.self, forKey: .assistant)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

For example in the following response, in the boss section, personType is set to 'Boss'. So it should be decoded to the Boss type. If it were 'Employee' it should automatically decode to Employee or if it null is should decode to 'Person'.

```
{ name: 'Shahid Khaliq',
  age: 5147483645,
  address: 'H # 531, S # 20',
  uid: '123321',
  salary: 20000,
  department: 'Software Development',
  workingDays: [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday' ],
  boss:
   { personType: 'Boss',
     assistant: null,
     name: 'Zeeshan Ejaz',
     age: 5147483645,
     address: 'H # 531, S # 20',
     uid: '123321',
     birthday: '1994-02-13',
     birthtime: '1994-02-13T14:01:54.000Z',
     salary: 20000,
     department: 'Software Development',
     joiningDay: 'Saturday',
     workingDays: [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday' ],
     dependents: null,
     hiredAt: 'Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT',
     boss: null,
     promotedAt: 1484719381 },
  dependents: null,
  hiredAt: 'Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT',
  personType: null }
```

Comment: discriminate? Can you show what is your server response? In overall coddle should be used if you know what type you want to decode

Comment: @Lu_ I have edited and added the server response example to make it more clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Need to change model as per current response you posted**

```
public class Employee: Person {

  public let department: String
  public let dependents: [Person]?
  public let salary: Int
  public let workingDays:[String] //[Days]
  public var boss: Person?

 private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case department
    case dependents
    case salary
    case workingDays
    case boss
 }


  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
     let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

     department = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .department)
    //dependents = try container.decode([Person].self, forKey: .dependents)
    dependents = try container.decodeIfPresent([Person].self, forKey: .dependents)
    salary = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .salary)
    // workingDays = try container.decode([Days].self, forKey: .workingDays)
    workingDays = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .workingDays)
   // boss = try container.decode(Person.self, forKey: .boss)
    boss = try container.decodeIfPresent(Person.self, forKey: .boss)
    try super.init(from: decoder)
 }
}
```

here added **decodeIfPresent** in few properties as it null as per current response

while decoding you can use different thing, i have used SwiftJSON to make code more readable ,

```
    // i have saved response in Response.JSON file so can change response as per need while testing below code.
    let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Response", ofType: "JSON")
    let dataURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: file!)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: dataURL)
    let jsonData = try! JSON(data: data)
    //here JSON is struct which is part of SwiftyJSON

    print("jsondata \(jsonData)")
    do {

        let bossDict = jsonData["boss"]
        let dataBoss : Data = try! bossDict.rawData() 
        let bossType = bossDict["personType"].string
            if let type = bossType {
                if type == "Boss"{
                    let bossObj = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Boss.self, from: dataBoss)
                    print("boss name \(String(describing: bossObj.name))")
                    bossObj.listPropertiesWithValues()
                }else{
                    // type == "Employee"
                    let emplyeeObj = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: dataBoss)
                    print("Employee name \(String(describing: emplyeeObj.name))")
                    emplyeeObj.listPropertiesWithValues()
                }
            }else{
                //type = nil

            }

    }catch{
        print("exception \(error)")
    }
```

You can download working demo of the same at link
[DemoCodable](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pv_LDlkpv8PkEgqDDcgDx4N-3vBokWR0/view)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a switch statement at the end of the `init(from decoder:)` in the `Employee` class

```
    switch personType {
    case "Boss":
         boss = try container.decode(Boss.self, forKey: .boss)
    case "Employee":
        boss = try container.decode(Employee.self, forKey: .boss)
    default:
        boss = nil
    }
```